# Kotlin - Retain RecyclerView position on activity restart

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How can the position of a `RecyclerView` be retained when `Activity` has restarted? I've considered using something like `savedInstanceState` but there doesn't seem to be a simple away of doing this without using dozens of lines of code.

**Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.md)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.master_container, MyFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var myAdapter: AdapterMain? = null
    private val myList = ArrayList<RVItem>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false)

        myRecyclerView = view.myRecyclerView

        myList.add(RVItem("Item A"))
        myList.add(RVItem("Item B"))
        myList.add(RVItem("Item C"))
        ...
        myList.add(RVItem("Item Y"))
        myList.add(RVItem("Item Z"))

        myAdapter = AdapterMain(activity!!, myList)

        myRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        val mInflater = Objects.requireNonNull<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity>(activity).menuInflater
        mInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_restart -> {
                restartActivity()

                true
            }

            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    private fun restartActivity() {
        startActivity(
            Intent(view!!.context, MainActivity::class.java)
        )

        activity!!.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
        activity!!.finish()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` restores scroll position natively by implementing view save state and requires no extra code on your part.

What you're doing incorrectly is "restarting" your activity. By calling `start` and `finish` you're destroying current activity and creating new instance. It will never receive `savedInstanceState` because it's not the same activity.

Instead you should use [`activity.recreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate()) to properly recreate the activity instance. It will receive `savedInstanceState` and implicitly restore view state including `RecyclerView` scroll.

Comment: Understood, but where does `activity!!.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)` need to go, so that the animation takes place when the `Activity` restarts?

Comment: @MacaronLover `recreate` does not support transitions or animations. If you really need that fade animation you'll need to find another way to make it work.

Comment: That's why I used the code that was in my question.